# Web.py - prevent caching of code/output

Tags: python, caching, nginx, fastcgi

This problem is baffling because the behavior is quite inconsistent.

I am learning about writing apps for the Web.py framework. For example, I have the following structure:

```
web_app/
 |-- main.py
 |-- api_calls
 |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |-- test1.py
 |    |-- test2.py
 \----\-- common.py
```

I call `spawn-fcgi` to start my web app as follows: `spawn-fcgi -s /run/webapp.sock -U http -G http /srv/http/web_app/main.py`.

Now, since I'm still learning how to write web apps this way, I am frequently updating the code. I have some functions in `common.py` which all of the "API files" may call, so they `import common`. In short, all of the import logic I expect to work does in fact work.

The problem is that if I change a piece of code, it seems highly inconsistent whether the web server, the fcgi process, or Python itself, detects this change and responds by executing the new code. For example. if I make a change in `common.py`, then other files which call it still reference the old code. However, if I make a change in `test1.py` or `main.py` then these changes **may** appear immediately upon a page reload. Again, though, even this seems inconsistent - sometimes it doesn't work.

I found that `touch`ing all of the .py files **sometimes** works to force the server to update, but again not always.

The only surefire way it seems to get new code to run consistently is to:

1. kill the Python process the spawn-fcgi program started
2. touch all .py files
3. remove all .pyc files
4. restart the spawn-fcgi daemon.

My question is two-fold: Can someone explain how the combination of Python, web.py, spawn-fcgi, and nginx handles code and page response caching? And secondly, is what I specified the only reliable way to ensure that any change I make to the code will be noticed when I refresh the webpage to see my changes? (Right now I am manually executing `ps` to find the correct Python process as I have other Python daemons running, then using `find` to touch `.py` and remove `.pyc` files, and then manually re-entering the spawn-fcgi command I indicated above - a tedious procedure when I may have only changed a single line of code...)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to write a small script alias to manually kill the fcgi process, delete the .pyc files, and restart the fcgi process. It works, but it's certainly not elegant...

```
alias newcode='kill `cat /run/fcgi-api.pid` ; sleep 0.5 && rm -f /mnt/data/www/api/*.pyc /run/fcgi-api.sock && spawn-fcgi -P /run/fcgi-api.pid -U http -G http -s /run/fcgi-api.sock /mnt/data/www/api/api.py'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue! web.py was giving cached results from old code. I had to restart Apache to prevent this from happening using `apache2ctl restart`.